# MySQL nested query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE.

I have following tables with columns:

```
Artist (artistId, name, dateOfBirth, dateOfDeath, homeCountry)
Picture (picId, name, artistId, value)
Museum (museumName, city, country)
Exhibited (picId, museumName, from, to)
```

And I want to achieve the answer of this question:

```
The museums (with name and city) which exhibit or exhibited pictures
of **all** the artists born between 1920 and 1950.
```

Queries I have tried so far:

```
SELECT museum.museumName, museum.city, COUNT(artist.artistId) AS C FROM museum

INNER JOIN exhibited ON exhibited.museumName = museum.museumName
INNER JOIN picture ON picture.picId = exhibited.picId
INNER JOIN artist ON artist.artistId = picture.artistId

WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN 2000 AND 2004
GROUP BY museum.museumName
HAVING COUNT(C) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN 2000 AND 2004);

------------------------

SELECT museumName, city FROM museum WHERE museumName IN 
(SELECT museumName FROM exhibited WHERE picId IN
 (SELECT picId FROM Picture WHERE artistId IN 
  (
   SELECT artistId FROM artist WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN 2000 AND 2004
  )
 )
);
```

There are other queries I've tried but cannot provide that I deleted since they did not help.

What query can print the asked data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is really close.  Instead of `count(c)` you need to count the artists and also to get the years right:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT artistId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist WHERE dateOfBirth BETWEEN 1920 AND 1950);
```

You also need to fix the `where` clause as well.  Not so many artists that are now shown in museums were born after 2000.

Comment: 2000 and 2004 years are just for test datas. I have some test data in DB. Thank you, that worked.